# git stash is slow on windows

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, git-stash

On my windows machine `git stash` has about 3.5 seconds overhead on each invocation, which adds about 7 seconds to my git commit hook.

The same command under linux (same machine) takes about 0.01 seconds. The performance issue applies to empty repositories as well.

I have tried the following from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485059/git-bash-is-extremely-slow-in-windows-7-x64) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835775/msysgit-bash-is-horrendously-slow-in-windows-7/2967519#2967519):

- `core.fscache` is set to `true`
- `core.preloadindex` is set to `true`
- `gc.auto` is set to `256`
- Setting PS1='$ '
- Running cmd in administration mode
- Running inside *cmd.exe* instead of git-bash

Running `GIT_TRACE=true git stash list`

```
16:58:16.844591 git.c:563               trace: exec: 'git-stash' 'list'
16:58:16.844591 run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: 'git-stash' 'list'
16:58:19.699591 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-dir'
16:58:19.859591 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-path' 'objects'
16:58:20.069591 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--show-toplevel'
16:58:20.154591 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-path' 'index'
16:58:20.244591 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-colorbool' 'color.interactive'
16:58:20.334591 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' 'color.interactive.help' 'red bold'
16:58:20.424591 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' '' 'reset'
16:58:20.514591 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--verify' '--quiet' 'refs/stash'

real    0m3.845s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.047s
```

Running `GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=true git stash list`

```
16:59:18.414591 trace.c:420             performance: 0.001078046 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' 'rev-parse' '--git-dir'                                          
16:59:18.569591 trace.c:420             performance: 0.000947184 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' 'rev-parse' '--git-path' 'objects'                               
16:59:18.779591 trace.c:420             performance: 0.001253627 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' 'rev-parse' '--show-toplevel'                                    
16:59:18.869591 trace.c:420             performance: 0.001285517 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' 'rev-parse' '--git-path' 'index'                                 
16:59:18.955591 trace.c:420             performance: 0.001139994 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' 'config' '--get-colorbool' 'color.interactive'                   
16:59:19.040591 trace.c:420             performance: 0.001182881 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' 'config' '--get-color' 'color.interactive.help' 'red bold'       
16:59:19.125591 trace.c:420             performance: 0.001128997 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' 'config' '--get-color' '' 'reset'                                
16:59:19.215591 trace.c:420             performance: 0.001567766 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' 'rev-parse' '--verify' '--quiet' 'refs/stash'                    
16:59:19.295591 trace.c:420             performance: 3.730583540 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe' 'stash' 'list'                                                                

real    0m3.819s                                                                                                                                                                                          
user    0m0.000s                                                                                                                                                                                          
sys     0m0.062s
```

From the log we see that it takes around 3 seconds between the git-stash command is run and the git-rev-parse is run. Are there any other flags I can run to find the bottleneck?

Comment: It's possible your repository is big, could you try to launch `git gc` on your local AND remote repository ?

Comment: It takes the same amount of time in an empty repository. I have updated the question.

Comment: @sighol have you gone through [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485059/git-bash-is-extremely-slow-in-windows-7-x64) and tested [this hint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2967519/365237)

Comment: @eis Yes, I have read those threads. They don't seem to work for me. I have updated the question.

Comment: is the local git repo hosted on your local drive or a remote/network one?

Comment: @g19fanatic no, it's hosted on my computer

Comment: Where is the gitconfig file? Isn't it on a remote disk? It should be be in your home directory, but I've seen cases in which this user dir was a remote one, leading to terrible performances.

Comment: If you just want things to work faster, you can try to create a temp branch, commit everything there and you'll have the same effect as if you stashed your changes (I do it like that frequently). But if you asked the question to get a better understanding of how the stash feature works, then you could maybe check the git source code: https://github.com/git/git

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP using git-for-windows 2.11.1.windows.1. My gitconfig is on a local SSD, and so is the repository. @MladenB. while it is possible to achieve the same results using branches, it takes several more steps as to make it impractical (as bad or worse than using the slow stash). Besides, the whole point of stash is to not create a commit recorded in history.

Comment: @PascalLeMerrer All other commands (that I've noticed) are reasonably fast. checkout, branch, status, add, commit, and take less than a second to execute. It's just stash that's super slow (15 seconds in my case).

Comment: See https://github.com/msysgit/git/issues/259. It's dated but closed (msysgit). Someone also opened https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159850/git-stash-on-windows-extremly-slow-compared-to-libgit2 recently.

Comment: Antivirus/Firewall?

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/git/git/pull/495

Comment: Can you try with Git 2.19? (Sept. 2018): git stash is now rewritten in C, even though the script version is still there by default: see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52318372/6309).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With [Git for Windows 2.19](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.19.0.windows.1) (Sept. 2018), `git stash` (and `git rebase`) are no longer script-only, but actually a binary compiled with `git.exe`.
See [git-for-windows/build-extra PR 203](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/pull/203).

<del>To activate them, type</del>:

```
git config --global rebase.useBuiltin true
git config --global stash.useBuiltin true
```

**Warning**:

> As nice as the speed-ups are, the patches in question are still in flux, and they are not battle-tested at all.

So, for now, the script version of `git stash` remains the default, that way:

> - users who want the raw speed improvement we got through three Google Summer of Code projects working in parallel can have that,
> - while others who are reluctant to play guinea pig by running only well-tested code can stay on the safe side.

The point remains: in the next versions of Git, the bash script for `git-stash` will eventually disappear, and its replacement is and will be faster.

Note: that next version will be Git 2.27 (Q2 2020): "`git stash`" has kept an escape hatch to use the scripted version for a few releases, which got stale.

It has been removed.

See [commit 8a2cd3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a2cd3f5123ac822fd64ca8efc4f84e122a1edb3), [commit b0c7362](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0c7362d19a83d45798085f26d98e39c9268e7e5) (03 Mar 2020) by [Thomas Gummerer (`tgummerer`)](https://github.com/tgummerer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 369ae75](https://github.com/git/git/commit/369ae7567a4621aa81e5c4decc27715418564ac2), 27 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`stash`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a2cd3f5123ac822fd64ca8efc4f84e122a1edb3): remove the `stash.useBuiltin` setting
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Thomas Gummerer</sup>

> Remove the `stash.useBuiltin` setting which was added as an escape hatch to disable the builtin version of stash first released with Git 2.22.
>
> Carrying the legacy version is a maintenance burden, and has in fact become out of date failing a test since the 2.23 release, without anyone noticing until now.
>
> So users would be getting a hint to fall back to a potentially buggy version of the tool.
>
> We used to shell out to [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) to get the `useBuiltin` configuration to avoid changing any global state before spawning legacy-stash.
> However that is no longer necessary, so just use the '`git_config`' function to get the setting instead.
>
> Similar to what we've done in [d03ebd411c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d03ebd411c651641eab823f0807705f4af65c9b1) ("`rebase`: remove the rebase.useBuiltin setting", 2019-03-18, Git v2.22.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f3036cfa1ffe2470f1afafe541fea8d58d9282b) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ffac537e6cbbf934b08745a378932722df287a53)), where we remove the corresponding setting for rebase, we leave the documentation in place, so people can refer back to it when searching for it online, and so we can refer to it in the commit message.

---

Update Q2 2019, with Git 2.22, `git stash` is entirely rewritten in C.
²
See [commit 40af146](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40af14683432285b94407e8488eab6942d0779dc), [commit 48ee24a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48ee24ab72b4ffd40789a99281066d79c2c5a720), [commit ef0f0b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef0f0b4509ae8bd6736dacf740d9e1bc1281f7bd), [commit 64fe9c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64fe9c26a479082eb80a9d68e8b3b7686e8c2b26), [commit 1ac528c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ac528c0b0c3f3e8a5faa75ea25f422fcbc2ba39), [commit d553f53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d553f538b8a788a4a285af2000edf3285694182e), [commit d4788af](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4788af875cc5c027c42b85435b022edb00b9fda), [commit 41e0dd5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/41e0dd55c4300dc83ea2883bf04bfb234c071f98), [commit dc7bd38](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc7bd382b1063303f4f45d243bff371899285acb), [commit 130f269](https://github.com/git/git/commit/130f2697daf60f09a15884a4510b4fa0230eee98), [commit bef55dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bef55dcf27060e57512ad99318a0d7de5b4ed6bb), [commit dac566c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dac566c507baeb4921e1b8ad8d39e8145ca80c12), [commit ab8ad46](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab8ad46ec70afbc0468c2c2cff817dc54c66ca79) (25 Feb 2019) by [Paul-Sebastian Ungureanu (`weekly-digest[bot]`)](https://github.com/weekly-digest%5Bbot%5D).
See [commit c4de61d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4de61d7a95ebb7197191bc51475d19068b6d526), [commit 577c199](https://github.com/git/git/commit/577c1995e8c8cb414a6beb430f220e1ded216a64), [commit 4e2dd39](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e2dd393031bba5abf32f1df6aff107903cabcfd), [commit 8a0fc8d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a0fc8d19dff0c0ed09ce6656e353daf06c21892) (25 Feb 2019) by [Joel Teichroeb (`klusark`)](https://github.com/klusark).
See [commit 7906af0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7906af0cb84c8e65656347909abd4e22b04d1c1e), [commit 90a4627](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90a462725ef3932a2408e78a47e3dfc1b8d445cf), [commit 8d8e9c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d8e9c2a94c4cb60a0db2a496fd1f28fc6ec79f8) (25 Feb 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e36adf7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e36adf712251a19bd2ada0016764d340dfcf2ba0), 22 Apr 2019)</sup>

You can still [use the shell script with `git legacy-stash`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90a462725ef3932a2408e78a47e3dfc1b8d445cf).

And:

> ### [`stash`: convert `stash--helper.c` into `stash.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40af14683432285b94407e8488eab6942d0779dc)

> The old shell script `git-stash.sh`  was removed and replaced entirely by `builtin/stash.c`.
> In order to do that, `create` and `push` were adapted to work without `stash.sh`.
>
> For example, before this commit, `git stash create` called `git stash--helper create --message "$*"`. If it called `git stash--helper create "$@"`, then
> some of these changes wouldn't have been necessary.
>
> This commit also removes the word `helper` since now stash is
> called directly and not by a shell script.

There are optimizations:

> ### [`stash`: optimize `get_untracked_files()` and `check_changes()`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef0f0b4509ae8bd6736dacf740d9e1bc1281f7bd)

> This commits introduces a optimization by avoiding calling the
> same functions again.
> For example, `git stash push -u` would call at some points the following functions:
>
> - `check_changes()` (inside `do_push_stash()`)
> - `do_create_stash()`, which calls: `check_changes()` and
>   `get_untracked_files()`
>
> Note that `check_changes()` also calls `get_untracked_files()`.
> So, `check_changes()` is called 2 times and `get_untracked_files()`
> 3 times.
>
> The old function `check_changes()` now consists of two functions:
> `get_untracked_files()` and `check_changes_tracked_files()`.
>
> These are the call chains for `push` and `create`:
>
> - `push_stash()` -> `do_push_stash()` -> `do_create_stash()`
> - `create_stash()` -> `do_create_stash()`
>
> To prevent calling the same functions over and over again, `check_changes()` inside `do_create_stash()` is now placed in the caller functions (`create_stash()` and `do_push_stash()`).
> This way `check_changes()` and `get_untracked files()` are called
> only one time.

---

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), removal of the warning "`the stash.useBuiltin support has been removed!`" is finally done!

See [commit e9b272e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9b272e4c1cb9742452ad44d42cedd407b6b5de2), [commit deeaf5e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/deeaf5ee077802f3e5bb4f52b4f14e61bdbe2a8e), [commit 5d4dc38](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d4dc38bfd484fda1944f131189f7e53abb90c1d), [commit 6de0722](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6de07229ac1dd269e12f941f701432b61dc43ad3) (27 Jan 2022) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b9f791a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9f791aee653932e87d558e5fd841d3394c70727), 16 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`stash`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9b272e4c1cb9742452ad44d42cedd407b6b5de2): stop warning about the obsolete `stash.useBuiltin` config setting
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> In [8a2cd3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a2cd3f5123ac822fd64ca8efc4f84e122a1edb3) ("`stash`: remove the stash.useBuiltin setting", 2020-03-03, Git v2.27.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/369ae7567a4621aa81e5c4decc27715418564ac2) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3bab5d56259722843359702bc27111475437ad2a)), we removed support for `stash.useBuiltin`, but left a warning in its place.
>
> After almost two years, and several major versions, it is time to remove even that warning.

Comment: Thank you! It works fast now. For small changes, it takes about 0.3s on my computer to use the stash.

Comment: no improvement whatsoever on git version 2.18.0.windows.1

Comment: @JerryGoyal But 2.18 seems old. 2.21 is the current version, is able to list commits faster (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53382508/6309) and has further improvements on rebase (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54973838/6309)

Comment: See also "[Git stash on windows extremely slow compared to Libgit2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59347116/6309)

Comment: Does this include `git stash push --patch`? It's always been glacially slow, especially on large repos, even  with pathspec 

Comment: @CervEd Not sure. Did you test it with Git 2.38+ on both end? And with [Scalar activated](https://github.blog/2022-10-13-the-story-of-scalar/).

Answer (score 3):

[update] as mentioned by VonC in his answer:

as of git 2.19 (Sept. 2018), `git stash` is a built-in command and not an external script anymore.

The following directions do not apply anymore if you are using `git` 2.19 or later.

---

`git-stash` is a script, not a command compiled in the `git.exe` binary.

On linux : I can find `git-stash` at `/usr/lib/git-core/git-stash` - I will let you look for the correct path on windows ...

---

This script uses `#!/bin/sh` to run, I don't know what shell implementation is used when you run this on windows.

You can try to run it with another compatible shell (here: bash) :

```
# the git-core/ dir needs to be in the PATH,
# obviously  you will need to provide the correct path for your git-core dir

$ PATH=/usr/lib/git-core:$PATH bash /usr/lib/git-core/git-stash
```

You can also turn the `-x` flag, which will print a trace of all commands executed, and visually check if one of the sub commands seems to be the hanger :

```
$ PATH=/usr/lib/git-core:$PATH bash -x /usr/lib/git-core/git-stash
```

Comment: on windows `sh` is `bash --posix`, AFAIK