# Git stash on windows extremly slow compared to Libgit2

Tags: c#, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp, git-for-windows

Recently I've been using git stash many times and I've been thinking that it is really slow, even on a new repository with a single file. I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529016/git-stash-is-slow-on-windows) about git stash slowness and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485059/git-bash-is-extremely-slow-in-windows-7-x64) and tried every answer to these questions but nothing actually works.

For example I've done the following steps to reproduce it:

1. `git init`
2. `touch file.txt`
3. `vim file.txt` (edit the file adding 2 lines)
4. `git add .`
5. `git commit -m "Initial commit"`
6. `vim file.txt` (edit it again adding 1 line)
7. `time git stash`

Output:

```
$ time git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: b9454ed Initial commit
HEAD is now at b9454ed Initial commit    
real    0m8.042s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.046s
```

8 seconds for stashing a single line is so much time. 
Now a test using libgit2sharp:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Repository repo=new Repository(@"C:\Users\UserTest\TestGitRepo");

    repo.Stashes.Add(new Signature("test", "test@test.com", new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now)), "Stash on master");
}
```

This code takes 74ms to stash the same change.
If Libgit2  is that fast then it should be possible to speed up `git stash` command. How can I achieve this?

Actually using windows 10 64bit and git 2.11 64bits. Other git commands (like status, add, commit, etc.) work fine.

UPDATE: I've updated to git 2.13 and now it's 14,53s for `git stash`...

UPDATE 2: I've updated to git 2.15 and trying the same test `time git stash` returns `real 0m6,553s`. Still really slow...

Comment: Actually, on my computer a `sh.exe.stackdump` is created, can you verify that `git stash` actually did what it was supposed to do?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen it did what is expected. The last line is stashed in both cases using the steps of my question.

Comment: Yes, the line is stashed on my end as well, but bash also crashed with a stack overflow. But this does not account for the time taken so just ignore my comments.

Comment: Agh, for some reason I had managed to go back to the 64-bit version of git which has problems with stack overflow exceptions in bash. Restored 32-bit and the crash dump went away.

Comment: I am using 64 bits git without crashes.

Comment: I know. Some people, like me, experience problems with some commands on 64-bit, rebasing and now apparently stashing, have problems. Installing a 32-bit client removes all the problems though.

Comment: Numerous Git commands are written as shell scripts. On Linux and Unix systems these run in perfectly reasonable time. On Windows, apparently (I don't use Windows so I have not experienced this), they run excruciatingly slowly. As a result, the Git folks have been rewriting more and more Git commands to avoid the use of shell scripts. I wonder if it might be more profitable to fix whatever is causing the shell to be so slow, but perhaps that's something fundamental to Windows.

Comment: Can be improved the performance of these scripts? It's too much time for a single line to wait 8 secs...

Comment: You could check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4485059/2303202) for recipes though I should say I do not remember any tweak helped me noticeably.

Comment: I've tried them but still the same :s

Comment: See https://github.com/msysgit/git/issues/259. It's dated but was closed (msysgit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Since Git 2.22**

Since Git 2.22 the previously experimental feature is now stable and the default option.

**Below Git 2.22**

One year later,  installing Git 2.19 I've seen a checkbox during git installation to enable the new **experimental** built-in stash.

[image: Experimental built-in git stash]

In my case it works fine and I've noticed a *huge* performance improvement compared to the old implementation (which was using a script) and it's actually as fast as using the same command in linux.

Here the results following exactly the same steps:

```
$ time git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 7a29b92 Initial commit

real    0m0,120s
user    0m0,000s
sys     0m0,015s
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the existing answer you can enable the new feature if you’ve already installed 2.19 or later with:

```
git config --global stash.usebuiltin true
```

This works with the portable edition as well.

Please note that this feature doesn’t seem to work with submodules yet.
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1820

Comment: Looks like they closed off that bug not long after your answer!

Answer (score 1):

[`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) will be faster with Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), where users of `oneway_merge()` (like "reset --hard") learned to take advantage of [`fsmonitor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56676917/6309) to avoid unnecessary [`lstat`(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56676917/6309) calls.

(Since Git 2.22, Q2 2019, [`git stash` is entirely rewritten in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52318372/6309), and is the default)

See [commit 679f2f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/679f2f9fdd2173d87251aee357dd0e46ce977f42) (20 Nov 2019) by [Utsav Shah (`Utsav2`)](https://github.com/Utsav2).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 473b431](https://github.com/git/git/commit/473b431410f5dbaa0c6a7bcc1e49b73c505cfe89), 05 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`unpack-trees`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/679f2f9fdd2173d87251aee357dd0e46ce977f42): skip stat on fsmonitor-valid files
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
>   <sup>Helped-by: Kevin Willford</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Utsav Shah</sup>
>
> The index might be aware that a file hasn't modified via `fsmonitor`, but unpack-trees did not pay attention to it and checked via `ie_match_stat` which can be inefficient on certain filesystems.
>   This significantly slows down commands that run `oneway_merge`, like `checkout` and [`git reset --hard`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt---hard).
>
> This patch makes `oneway_merge` check whether a file is considered unchanged through `fsmonitor` and skips `ie_match_stat` on it.
>   unpack-trees also now correctly copies over `fsmonitor` validity state from the source index.
>   Finally, for correctness, we force a refresh of `fsmonitor` state in `tweak_fsmonitor`.
>
> After this change, commands like **`stash`** (that use [`git reset --hard`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt---hard) internally) **go from 8s or more to ~2s on a 250k file repository on a mac**.