# git - have log commits but missing .sln file so cannot open project - how to restore

Tags: git

Is there any way to restore my project files using git.

Here is the scenario....
I worked on a branch for few days.  **This branch was never pushed to remote repo**, so it is entirely local.

I ended up loosing my .sln solution file so I cannot open the project any more but in the project directory I do have the .git directory still.

If I issue git log, I can see it lists commit far back so the logs seem to exists.

is there a way to somehow find files in these logs or restore my project based on the commits in log?  Or is there some other way?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @RomainValeri, `git checkout <commit-hash>` works but it sets HEAD in detached state.  While that might not be big deal, later I found that `git reset --hard HEAD~1` works better since I dont need to keep changes in last commit, so using `--hard` discards them.  If you need to keep these changes, using `--soft` instead will reset HEAD to your commit before last commit and add changes in last commit to staging area.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git reset --hard HEAD~2
git reset --hard HEAD~3
...
```

Above commands reset HEAD pointer 1, 2, 3, ... commits before last commit and discard any changes after.  Use --soft instead of --hard if you dont want to discard these changes in which case these changes will be staged for you.

Comment: in addition to pulling it from your git repo, a sln file is really just a collection of project files, and should be fairly easy to recreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the very principle of git : being able to restore a codebase at different points in its development.

Basically, any commit is a snapshot.

So be reassured : if you see a long list of logs, you're not just reading a static log. This output is built at execution from the commits available in your git repo. And commits contain everything. Each commit is a full copy of the code base.

If you do

```
git checkout <commitHash>
```

the working tree (the directory with the system of files linked to the repo) will be updated to reflect the state described in the given commit.

You can find these commit hashes with the `git log` command you already know, so use it to read the commit messages to determine which snapshot you want to inspect, store/copy its hash ([what is a SHA-1 hash?](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)), and check it out.