# git rebase stopped working in git for windows

Tags: git, crash, rebase

I'm observing very strange crashes in git rebase. 
Operations that I'm performing haven't change, but their result has changed since some time ago.

Instead of rebased branch I get help message from git rebase, describing command line options, and file `bash.exe.stackdump` with some hex numbers.

The same behavior is observed during execution of `git pull --rebase`. Rebasing pulled commits is my default setting therefore this misbehavior is very annoying.

Example:

```
$ git rebase master feature/tune-logging
usage: git rebase [-i] [options] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>] [<upstream>] [<branch>]
   or: git rebase [-i] [options] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>] --root [<branch>]
   or: git rebase --continue | --abort | --skip | --edit-todo

Available options are
    -v, --verbose         display a diffstat of what changed upstream
    -q, --quiet           be quiet. implies --no-stat
    --autostash           automatically stash/stash pop before and after
    --fork-point          ....

    [ skip ... ] 

Actions:
    --continue            continue
    --abort               abort and check out the original branch
    --skip                skip current patch and continue
    --edit-todo           edit the todo list during an interactive rebase
    --quit                abort but keep HEAD where it is
    --show-current-patch  show the patch file being applied or merged
```

I use Windows 7 x64, with recent updates. 
git version 2.18.0.windows.1

I also use SmartGit, running the same git executable.

Here is the output, obtained with `GIT_TRACE=2`

```
$ GIT_TRACE=2 git rebase master feature/tune-logging                                                                             
11:13:05.925709 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin                         
11:13:05.927709 git.c:654               trace: exec: git-rebase master feature/tune-logging                                      
11:13:05.927709 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: git-rebase master feature/tune-logging                               
11:13:06.348751 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core            
11:13:09.354050 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core            
11:13:09.356050 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-dir                                                 
11:13:09.778092 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core            
11:13:09.779092 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-path objects                                        
11:13:10.122126 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core            
11:13:10.123126 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --is-bare-repository                                      
11:13:10.452159 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core            
11:13:10.453159 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --show-toplevel                                           
11:13:10.827196 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core            
11:13:10.829197 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git config --bool rebase.stat                                           
11:13:11.210235 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core            
11:13:11.212235 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git config --bool rebase.autostash                                      
11:13:11.548269 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core            
11:13:11.550269 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git config --bool rebase.autosquash                                     
11:13:11.869301 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core            
11:13:11.871301 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git config --bool commit.gpgsign                                        
11:13:12.330347 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core            
11:13:12.754389 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core            
11:13:12.755389 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --parseopt --stuck-long -- -h                             
usage: git rebase [-i] [options] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>] [<upstream>] [<branch>]                                       
   or: git rebase [-i] [options] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>] --root [<branch>]                                             
   or: git rebase --continue | --abort | --skip | --edit-todo                                                                    

Available options are                                                                                                            
    -v, --verbose         display a diffstat of what changed upstream                                                            
    -q, --quiet           be quiet. implies --no-stat                                                                            
    --autostash           automatically stash/stash pop before and after                                                         

  [skip ]
```

Branches `master` and `feature/tune-logging` do exist.

**UPDATE**.

Tried rolling-back git to some previous version.

1. Randomly chosen git version 2.12.2 worked fine, but caused complains of the SmartGit about too old git and suggestion to use version at least 2.16
2. Upgraded git to 2.16.2 - same crashes.

**UPDATE 2**.

I describe my experiments.

Create a new branch on some old commit from the master, add dummy file, commit, delete dummy file, commit, rebase:

```
--c1--c2--c3--master
   \
    d1-add dummy file--d2-remove dummy file--
```

**UPDATE 3**

Tried git versions 2.15 and 2.14. Version 2.15 gives the same crashes, version 2.14 works.

Will stop on it for now, until the reason of crashes will be resolved. I'll try to provide additional information on order to find it.

**UPDATE 4**

I usually work with the SmartGit, which is a GUI front-end to git, but all the results above were obtained using command line.

Comment: What is your aim? To rebase `feature/tune-logging` on to `master`?

Comment: Yes. And another aim is to make rebase working. I repeat the experiment: create new branch on some old commit in master, add dummy file, commit, remove dummy file, rebase.

Comment: Before you try any rebase, always create a branch from the branch you're going to rebase.

Comment: Try checking out `feature/tune-logging` and running `git rebase master`?

Comment: I do it in SmartGit, it checks it out.

Comment: Try it on the command line?

Comment: Tried with the same result. git trace was obtained from the command line.

Comment: Interesting. The tracing shows that it's working, up to some point, after which it runs `git rev-parse` with `-h` which is the "show the help" option. Clearly some sort of internal bug, probably specific to Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated git to 2.19, the issue has gone.

While installing new git version, setup wizard has shown two checkboxes, asking to turn on new experimental built-in features: rebase and stash.

I've left them unchecked.

[image: use external rebase and stash]

**Updated** to git 2.19.1.windows.1, now turned those checkboxes on. Everything still works.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `git rebase` is now more complete with Git 2.21 (Feb. 2019), since instead of going through "`git-rebase--am`" scriptlet to use the "`am`" backend, the built-in version of "git rebase" learned to drive the "`am`" backend directly.

See [commit 2185362](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21853626eac565dd42572d90724b29863f61eb3b), [commit 414f336](https://github.com/git/git/commit/414f336069adfaea76217387cd03beefb4d73a20), [commit 5b2237a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b2237a8761295a0027c7e055e6dfee0e30d5194), [commit c523370](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c5233708c5d67ffe78beb18a92794921b8e247d4) (18 Jan 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e52c6bb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e52c6bbd131f1f4f17b95e28d12ead0c81a8e890), 07 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### [`built-in rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21853626eac565dd42572d90724b29863f61eb3b): call `git am` directly
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> While the scripted `git rebase` still has to rely on the `git-rebase--am.sh` script to implement the glue between the `rebase` and the `am` commands, we can go a more direct route in the built-in rebase and avoid using a shell script altogether.

> This patch represents a straight-forward port of `git-rebase--am.sh` to C, along with the glue code to call it directly from within [`builtin/rebase.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/21853626eac565dd42572d90724b29863f61eb3b/builtin/rebase.c).

> This reduces the chances of Git for Windows running into trouble due to problems with the POSIX emulation layer (known as "MSYS2 runtime", itself a derivative of the Cygwin runtime): when no shell script is called, the POSIX emulation layer is avoided altogether.

(Actually, with Git 2.22, Q2 2019, the built-in rebase is complete and stable, and the [old script rebase is no more](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f3036cfa1ffe2470f1afafe541fea8d58d9282b))

---

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), "`git rebase --signoff`" stopped working when the command was written in C, which has been corrected.

See [commit 4fe7e43](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4fe7e43c53a6ad2948919503188bb2d34ce02fa9) (20 Dec 2019) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e0e1ac5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0e1ac5db0235abba4038cf571a949c3f8c1b65c), 02 Jan 2020)</sup>

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4fe7e43c53a6ad2948919503188bb2d34ce02fa9): fix saving of --signoff state for am-based rebases
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> This was an error introduced in the conversion from shell in [commit 21853626eac5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21853626eac565dd42572d90724b29863f61eb3b) ("built-in rebase: call `git am` directly", 2019-01-18, Git v2.21.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e52c6bbd131f1f4f17b95e28d12ead0c81a8e890), seen above), which was noticed by a random browsing of the code.

---

As noted in With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), "`git rebase`" now uses the "`--apply`" option to use the "`apply`" backend (e.g. the moral equivalent of "`format-patch piped to am`").

> The `rebase.backend` configuration variable can be set to customize.

See [commit 10cdb9f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10cdb9f38adaa16aad64403bc931405564523985), [commit 2ac0d62](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2ac0d6273fa6618e1a8783e07e2363b3abba1f2a), [commit 8295ed6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8295ed690bf1d458f80cffdc17d663eb3ba5162a), [commit 76340c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76340c8107ba8e658f9cc76d1d220bac2944d1f1), [commit 980b482](https://github.com/git/git/commit/980b482d28482c307648c3abbcb16ae60843c7ae), [commit c2417d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2417d3af7574adc1fb14f7df31b862aa9551e2e), [commit 6d04ce7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d04ce75c4dd4bf0aeda7383c4d791daa049c98a), [commit 52eb738](https://github.com/git/git/commit/52eb738d6b40bf8816727fcf7f39febc761ef0db), [commit 8af14f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8af14f08596197d53c40b71ed014b030956a12be), [commit be50c93](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be50c938dfc1555ea62df455a41138e41503b952), [commit befb89c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/befb89ce7c43a0bd0de11909951dd3015874e9db), [commit 9a70f3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a70f3d4ae673e02e78b1061fcc8fc01bc8d9276), [commit 93122c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93122c985a3671bd4e15b3dbc6b457c981eb8c23), [commit 55d2b6d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55d2b6d785da8c49d693d989c22f47622783903a), [commit 8a997ed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a997ed132f7b8709d1752b64779566600345375), [commit 7db00f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7db00f0b3bc2c0bde616d45cf6e3a130e74e3024), [commit e98c426](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e98c4269c86019bfe057a91b4305f784365b6f0b), [commit d48e5e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d48e5e21da980c6d439655a1292d0332b341c7d1) (15 Feb 2020), and [commit a9ae8fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9ae8fde2eb0c00723d850ba23ea8401864fab83), [commit 22a69fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22a69fda197f78410190469bf0fcb51f6f69730f) (16 Jan 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8c22bd9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c22bd9ff9d4a355d3546181698307a797fd2bd2), 02 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10cdb9f38adaa16aad64403bc931405564523985): rename the two primary rebase backends
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> Rename the 'am' backend to 'apply' because:
>
> - Few users are familiar with git-am as a reference point.
> - Related to the above, the name 'am' makes sentences in the documentation harder for users to read and comprehend (they may read it as the verb from "I am"); avoiding this difficult places a large burden on anyone writing documentation about this backend to be very careful with quoting and sentence structure and often forces annoying redundancy to try to avoid such problems.
> - Users stumble over pronunciation ("am" as in "I am a person not a backend" or "am" as in "the first and thirteenth letters in the alphabet in order are "A-M"); this may drive confusion when one user tries to explain to another what they are doing.
> - While "am" is the tool driving this backend, the tool driving git-am is git-apply, and since we are driving towards lower-level tools for the naming of the merge backend we may as well do so here too.
> - The directory where state is stored has never been called `.git/rebase-am`, it was always called `.git/rebase-apply`.

---

With Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2cbfbd2e28cbe27c194d62183b42f27a6a5bb87), hints that suggest what to do after resolving conflicts can now be squelched by disabling `advice.mergeConflict`.

cf.
h040h631-42d9-4501-a7b8-046f8dac6309@gmail.com

See [commit 37ce973](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37ce97353c5be708ce2f86e176e99b62507332cc), [commit ec03009](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec0300914b42277077f51a8c7e3438d7565eb261) (16 Mar 2024) by [Philippe Blain (`phil-blain`)](https://github.com/phil-blain).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ac16f55](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac16f55697211ae4ef557706a098b8ed34a7fda6), 01 Apr 2024)</sup>

> ### [`sequencer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec0300914b42277077f51a8c7e3438d7565eb261): allow disabling conflict advice
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philippe Blain</sup>

> Allow disabling the advice shown when a squencer operation results in a merge conflict through a new config 'advice.mergeConflict', which is named generically such that it can be used by other commands eventually.
>
> Remove that final '\n' in the first hunk in [`sequencer.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ec0300914b42277077f51a8c7e3438d7565eb261/sequencer.c) to avoid an otherwise empty 'hint: ' line before the line 'hint: Disable this message with "[`git config`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ec0300914b42277077f51a8c7e3438d7565eb261/Documentation/git-config.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))</sup> advice.mergeConflict false which is automatically added by '`advise_if_enabled`'.
>
> Note that we use '`advise_if_enabled`' for each message in the second hunk in [`sequencer.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ec0300914b42277077f51a8c7e3438d7565eb261/sequencer.c), instead of using 'if `(show_hints` && `advice_enabled(`...)', because the former instructs the user how to disable the advice, which is more user-friendly.
>
> Update the tests accordingly.
> Note that the body of the second test in t3507-cherry-pick-conflict.sh is enclosed in double quotes, so we must escape them in the added line.
> Note that t5520-pull.sh, which checks that we display the advice for '[`git rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ec0300914b42277077f51a8c7e3438d7565eb261/Documentation/git-rebase.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))</sup> (via '[`git pull --rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ec0300914b42277077f51a8c7e3438d7565eb261/Documentation/git-pull.txt#L108)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---rebasefalse%7Ctrue%7Cmerges%7Cinteractive))</sup>) does not have to be updated because it only greps for a specific line in the advice message.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ec0300914b42277077f51a8c7e3438d7565eb261/Documentation/config/advice.txt#L59-L60):

> ### `mergeConflict`
>
> Shown when various commands stop because of conflicts.